# css: child items bigger than parent (100% not working as expected)

Tags: html, css

I have this situation in which I'm using

```
height: 100%
```

on a parent, and in the parent I have this header which is 34px and a container which is 100% again.
For some reason the container (ordered list) is bigger than the parent

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu8QU/3/)

And here is the css

```
* {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
   padding: 10px 20px 20px 10px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}

header {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
}

ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px dashed #d2d4d8;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: green;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions why the ordered list is outside the parent `section` element ?

Comment: change your padding in section to padding: 10px 20px 40px 10px; (10px + your header height)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's setting the height of the `ol` to 100% of the parent height, not 100% of the parent minus the 30px for the header.  I've gotten frustrated at this before, because in my head I want 100% to mean "Fill to the parent" but it means literally 100%.  If you can do css3 stuff, you could change your css to this:

```
ol { height: calc(100% - 30px); }
```

You could also do some positioning stuff, but that always gets gross.  Here is an untested idea of it:

```
section { position: relative; }
ol { position: absolute; top: 30px; bottom: 0; }
```

Comment: thnx for the answer. I can use calc :) Anyway, because of this 100% not doing what I'm expecting it to do, I will checkout [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) too!

Comment: Flexbox is really the way forward, and super awesome once you wrap your head around it.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't help that your mixing percentages and fixed sizes with your padding. When you do that use `box-sizing:border-box;` so that the percentage based width and height will take into account the padding and margins and not just add them on the end.

Comment: Holy crap! Why is this not on by default?!?! If I say I want something to be 100%, it's because I want it to render at 100%! ‍♂️ Thank you so much for pointing this out. Adding a * rule for this in ALL my css now!

Comment: @eidylon because most people want the size to reflect the content area. You can control the size of the margin, padding and border with specific css instructions. But you can only control the content area using the width command. So by default width only controls the content area.